# UnsatisfiedLinkError, couldn't find "libsqlite3x.so" when using io.requery:sqlite-android:3.28.0

Tags: android, sqlite

How to solve this

```
Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/expand/77de0b21-1bc2-463c-99bd-bf0cc7b24a99/app/com.gazman.beep-1/base.apk", zip file "/mnt/expand/77de0b21-1bc2-463c-99bd-bf0cc7b24a99/app/com.gazman.beep-1/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk", zip file "/mnt/expand/77de0b21-1bc2-463c-99bd-bf0cc7b24a99/app/com.gazman.beep-1/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/mnt/expand/77de0b21-1bc2-463c-99bd-bf0cc7b24a99/app/com.gazman.beep-1/split_config.hdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/expand/77de0b21-1bc2-463c-99bd-bf0cc7b24a99/app/com.gazman.beep-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libsqlite3x.so"
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary + 367(Runtime.java:367)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary + 1076(System.java:1076)
   at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase. + 1(SourceFile:1)
   at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked + 16(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:241)
   at io.requery.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase + 3(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:199)
   at com.gazman.db.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase + 1(DataBaseHelper.java:73)
   at com.gazman.db.DataBaseHelper.load + 4(DataBaseHelper.java:42)
   at com.gazman.db.DataBase$Builder.lambda$build$0 + 7(DataBase.java:105)
   at com.gazman.db.-$$Lambda$DataBase$Builder$_hO1n5NrBU5iSRvioMNsgA9ortc.run(-.java)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 739(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 95(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 148(Looper.java:148)
   at com.gazman.db.DBThread$1.run + 3(DBThread.java:19)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 818(Thread.java:818)enter code here
```

This is my Crashalitics report:

[image]

It started after I added [sqlite-android](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android), it's an amazing Sqlite library that allows me to use the latest Sqlite version on all the Android versions, but then I am getting the above exception.

This is my build gradle SQL dependencies

```
implementation 'io.requery:sqlite-android:3.28.0'
implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Did you maybe add android _{ packagingOptions { exclude 'lib/..._ to your build.gradle file? Maybe it will help to add _android { defaultConfig { ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64" ..._

Comment: Maybe you can fix this with Relinker: https://github.com/KeepSafe/ReLinker

Comment: https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/issues/105 confirms that ReLinker does solve the issue.

Comment: @mtotschnig may I ask if you can confirm whether this actually fixed the issue for you in your app? I have been using ReLinker to attempt to fix this issue for well over a year in my app and I still get traces of this issue in my production app. I shared my continued discussion: https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android/issues/105#issuecomment-1426930973

Comment: @Brian I didn't try it

Comment: @Brian For me Relinker did not immediately fix the issue. Another change in my app lead to the issue no longer happening: Before I used Dagger to instantiate the RequerySQLiteOpenHelperFactory immediately when the graph was constructed, i.e. on App startup. Now I use javax.inject.Provider to lazily inject the provider into my content provider at the moment the database is created, which happens after onboarding in my case. Since then, this crash stopped appearing. I still use Relinker, but I suspect I would not need it anymore.

Comment: @mtotschnig I see, good to know. Interestingly I'm not using any DI in my app. I basically run ReLinker on app startup. I wonder if somehow the library can get unloaded during the app lifetime and needs to be reloaded.